# Play music dynamically in html

Tags: html, django, python-2.7

I am new to web technology , i am trying to play a music file dynamically using python django HTML. i have stored the file location in db and fetching it.

`<audio control><source src= {{track.songlocation}} type="audio/mpeg"></audio>`

i am getting following error

```
Not Found: /home/tushar/Music/Tracks/shots.mp3
```

while, if i statically play the file, its playing

```
<audio control><source src= "/home/tushar/Music/Tracks/shots.mp3" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```

How do i solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it does not work because of missing quotes

```
<audio control><source src="{{track.songlocation}}" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
```